# How to listen for changes to an object's property inside a View Model using Provider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

Let's say I have the following view model class

```
    class Foo extends ChangeNotifier{
      //Object variable to which changes will be made
      Object _fooObject = Object();
      
      // Getter and Setter of Object
        Object get fooObject => _fooObject;

      set fooObject(Object value) {
        _fooObject = value;
        notifyListeners();
       }  
    }
```

And let's say this is my Object Class

```
class Object{
int? property1;
String? property2;

Object(this.property1,this.property2);
}
```

Now If I assign a new Object() to fooObject the changes will easily reflect because I have called notifyListeners() in the setter but what If I change a single property in the fooObject let's say I do

```
Provider.of<Foo>(context).fooObject.property1 = 2;
```

How do I exactly detect these changes in realtime? do I have to make a separate getter setter for each property? What's the best solution to call notifyListeners() on property1's change?

Answer (score 0):

you can determine using the **identical(a , b)** function.

```
set fooObject(Object value) {
      if(identical(_fooObject , value)){
      _fooObject = value;
      notifyListeners();
   }
```

}